# Unable to join on conrelid and confrelid columns in pg_constraint

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

I'm trying to get a list of foreign key constraints in the following form:

```
pk_table | pk_col | fk_table | fk_col
```

without using `pg_get_constraintdef` (which would force me to resort to string manipulation).

Is there any reason why the following query doesn't work?

```
SELECT
  x.conname,
  x.contype,
  x.conrelid,
  x.confrelid,
  pk.tablename,
  fk.tablename
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint x 
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tables pk ON x.conrelid!=0 AND x.conrelid=(pk.tablename :: regclass :: oid)
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tables fk ON x.confrelid!=0 AND x.confrelid=(fk.tablename :: regclass :: oid)
WHERE
  x.connamespace in (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE n.nspname in ('b2b', 'public'))
  AND x.contype='f'
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  relation "sql_implementation_info" does not exist
```

My hypothesis was that PG is getting confused due to the presence of multiple namespaces, so I tried restricting the result-set to my known schemas, i.e. `b2b, public`, but this still doesn't work.

Comment: I installed psql the other day, so I tried your query and it works (0 rows returned of course, but no error). Tested on psql (9.6.4, server 9.6.3)

Comment: Can you try it on a DB which has some tables and FK constraints? My gut-feeling is that the query is well formed, but some rows are causing the error.

Comment: I'll add some info in an answer, it will be to long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that not all of "tables" presented in the `pg_tables` view have `OID` presented in the `pg_class` relation:

```
postgres=# select tablename::regclass from pg_catalog.pg_tables;
ERROR:  relation "sql_features" does not exist
```

You should to rewrite your query to more "low-level":

```
SELECT
  x.conname,
  x.contype,
  x.conrelid,
  x.confrelid,
  pk.relname,
  fk.relname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint x 
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class pk ON x.conrelid!=0 AND x.conrelid=pk.oid
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class fk ON x.confrelid!=0 AND x.confrelid=fk.oid
WHERE
  x.contype='f';
```

<kbd>[**test**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=baf539723f0ebad4ecf2f9bec8ee8e85)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I queried an empty database and your query was fine:

```
test=> SELECT
test->   x.conname,
test->   x.contype,
test->   x.conrelid,
test->   x.confrelid,
test->   pk.tablename,
test->   fk.tablename
test-> FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint x 
test-> INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tables pk ON x.conrelid!=0 AND         x.conrelid=(pk.tablename :: regclass :: oid)
test-> INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tables fk ON x.confrelid!=0 AND x.confrelid=(fk.tablename :: regclass :: oid)
test-> WHERE
test->   x.connamespace in (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE n.nspname in ('b2b', 'public'))
test->   AND x.contype='f';
 conname | contype | conrelid | confrelid | tablename | tablename 
---------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
(0 rows)
```

However when I created two tables with a foreign key:

```
test=> create table parent (x int not null primary key);
CREATE TABLE
test=> create table child (y int not null primary key, x int not null    references parent(x));
CREATE TABLE
```

I got the following :

```
ERROR:  relation "sql_features" does not exist
```

At first I thought it was a problem with my user but I got the same error when sudoing to psql.

So I started investigating the catalog in postgres, and I guess that you should be fine with information from constraint_column_usage and information_schema.table_constraints

```
select * from information_schema.constraint_column_usage;
select * from information_schema.table_constraints;
```

I'm not sure exactly what your query is supposed to return, so I'll leave it there.

I don't know if there are any drawbacks using information_schema vs pg_catalog (I suppose some psql specific stuff is not in information_schema), but the information_schema looks pretty much like information_schemas in other DBMS:s. So if you know your way around the information_schema in psql, you should be able to use that knowledge in other DBMS.